# Pogrammetically set category to enable in magento

Tags: magento

I am creating a new category form front end pro-grammatically..  whenever i run this script than new category creating but it can't set to active. so that it can't appear on the  top-menu.

my code is:-

```
$parentId = '2';     
    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->setName('abc');
    $category->setUrlKey('abc');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(1);   
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              
    $category->save();
    unset($category);
```

it can't set $category->setIsActive(1); please suggest me where i did some changes to set it enable.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to assign store id to category**

```
$parentId = '2';     
        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->setName('abc');
    $category->setStoreId( 0 ); // you have top set your store id to active category
        $category->setUrlKey('abc');
        $category->setIsActive(1);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1);   
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              
        $category->save();
        unset($category);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$categoryName = abc; // Name of Category

    // Create category object
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setStoreId(0); // No store is assigned to this category

    $rootCategory['name'] = $categoryName;
    $rootCategory['path'] = "1/2"; // this is the catgeory path - 1 for root category
    $rootCategory['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS";
    $rootCategory['is_active'] = 1;

    $category->addData($rootCategory);

    try {
    echo'<pre>';
    print_r($category);
    $category->save();
    $rootCategoryId = $category->getId();
    }
    catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

I think problem with path in your code, try it , if have any problem than let me know.